# XNA Windows Phone 7 Sprite movement

Tags: xna, 2d, sprite, windows-phone-7.1

I'm working on a Windows phone game and I'm having difficulty with the sprite movement.
What I want to do is make the sprite gradually move to the position that is touched on screen, when there is only one quick touch and release. 
At the minute all I can do is either make the sprite jump instantly to the touch location or move along to the touch location when the touch is held down.

Code for jumping to touch location:

```
TouchCollection touchCollection = TouchPanel.GetState();
        foreach (TouchLocation tl in touchCollection)
        {
            if ((tl.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed)
                 || (tl.State == TouchLocationState.Moved))
            {
                Vector2 newPos = new Vector2(tl.Position.X,tl.Position.Y);

                    if (position != newPos)
                    {
                        while (position.X < newPos.X)
                        {
                            position.X += (float)theGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds / 10.0f * spriteDirectionRight;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
```

Code to gradually move along while touch is held:

```
TouchCollection touchCollection = TouchPanel.GetState();
        foreach (TouchLocation tl in touchCollection)
        {
            if ((tl.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed)
                 || (tl.State == TouchLocationState.Moved))
            {
                Vector2 newPos = new Vector2(tl.Position.X,tl.Position.Y);

                    if (position != newPos)
                    {

                            position.X += (float)theGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds / 10.0f * spriteDirectionRight;

                    }
            }
         }
```

These are in the Update() method of the Sprite class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this...sorry I didn't run it through a compiler so there may be some syntax errors. Declare these as fields in the class:

```
Vector2 newPos;
bool moving = false;
```

then in the Update method:

```
        TouchCollection touchCollection = TouchPanel.GetState();
        foreach (TouchLocation tl in touchCollection)
        {
            if ((tl.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed)
                 || (tl.State == TouchLocationState.Moved)
                 || (tl.State == TouchLocationState.Released))
            {
                newPos = new Vector2(tl.Position.X, tl.Position.Y);
                moving = true;
            }
        }
        if (moving && newPos != position)
        {
            Vector2 delta = newPos - position;
            Vector2 norm = delta;
            norm.Normalize();
            Vector2 distanceToMove = norm * ((float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds * .5f);
            if (distanceToMove.LengthSquared() > delta.LengthSquared())
            {
                position = newPos;
                moving = false;
            }
            else
            {
                position += distanceToMove;
            }
        }
```

Comment: "Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'void' and 'float'"  Its giving me this error for                                      Vector2 distanceToMove = delta.Normalize() * (float)theGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds * 10f;"

Comment: Ok sorry I fixed it, forgot that Normalize modifies the existing Vector2 and doesn'r return one. I found another bug when I went to run it, this one has been tested.